# Pointer of an object in Java with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, pointers

I have two threads. One thread has an instance of myObjectManager. myObjectManager has a list of objects, and a method for retrieving an object( public myObjectClass getObjectById(int ID) )

I need the first thread to render an object in myObjectManagers list of objects, and the second thread to perform game logic and move it around etc.

This is what I tried

```
//thread 1:
m = myObjectManager.getObjectById(100);
m.render();

//thread 2:
m = myObjectManager.getObjectById(100);
m.rotate( m.getRotation() + 5 ); //increment rotation value
```

However, it seems that thread 1 has an instance of the object without the updated rotation.  When I run it, the rendered object doesn't rotate, but when I make the second thread print out the rotation value it is rotated.

In C++ I would just make the function getObjectById() return a pointer to an instance of myObjectClass, but I'm not sure what exactly java does when I say "return myInstance;"
How would I do something similar in java?

*Sorry, I'm new to this language!*

Comment: Are your objects thread-safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, all Object variables are "pointers" (or "references", as people typically say). The problem must be elsewhere. My guess is that thread 1 has already rendered the object before thread 2 has even modified it.

**Edit**: Another theory: subsequent render() operations don't actually change the screen display. The rotation value is updated just fine - but it doesn't reflect to the display.

Comment: Even if it did, thread 1 uses m.rotation to render the rotation. that value doesn't get reset or anything, and the ONLY place its modified is in the constructor of myObjectClass (to set it to 0) and in thread 2s run method

Comment: @AlexRamallo: I fail to see the contradiction. A. you create the object; rotation is 0. B. Thread 1 runs it, and renders it. Rotation is 0. C. Thread 2 runs it, modifies rotation, and sees rotation modified. Nothing changes in rendering since rendering was already done before.

Comment: Heres an image I made to try to explain what I mean: http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/5438/explains.jpg  Both threads run side-by-side so if they were accessing the same instance of m, then it wouldn't matter which one happens first because Thread 1 only READS and thread 2 is the one the WRITES. If thread 1 renders before thread 2 changes the rotation, then the rotation should be visible in the next frame. EDIT: the rotation never gets reset

Comment: @AlexRamallo: See my edit. Can you print out the rotation value in thread 1, and report whether the observed value changes (rather than just verifying whether the display changes)?

Comment: Thanks man I solved it before, shoulda chosen an answer earlier. The problem was actually that my rotation function was messed up, I updated position instead and it worked xD    but I did learn about synchronization though so it wasnt a total waste

Answer (score 3):

The references (pointers) are alright but in Java each thread is allowed to make local copies of objects (think of it like a cache) they're working with and unless they are synchronized in some way, changes made by one thread may not be visible to the other.

[This](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) tutorial will hopefully help.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 potential problems, both of which have been stated here in different answers.

1. You give no indication as to any
   control of ordering of your thread
   operations.  Therefore the render
   may be occurring before the rotation
   update.  This assumes that the the
   classes involved are in fact
   threadsafe and will behave as
   expected.
2. If the classes are not
       threadsafe (i.e. synchronized in
       some way), then the updates to the
       rotation thread may never be seen in
       the rendering thread.

To know for sure we would have to see the source for the **m** class.  Also, you may have issues with the getObjectById() as well if it is not threadsafe either.

Answer (score 1):

Try marking your `rotation` variable in the object as `volatile`

Answer (score 0):

All objects in Java are passed by reference.
It is impossible to write code that does what you're trying not to do.

Your first thread is probably running before the second thread.

Answer (score 0):

**All object references in Java**, like your m variable, **are in fact pointers**.

So in your example, both m variables point to the same object.